# Me mantiene siempre la sesion en php

Tags: php, login, sesiones

hola migos tengo un sistema de login el cual cuando debería expirar porque lo paso a otra pagina que no tiene session start no me expira. es decir siempre me mantiene las variables sesision llenas y no es lo que quiero dejo el codigo.
cuando refresco la pagina index o quiero llegar a ella por el navegador me sigue saliendo el mensaje de la condicion, como si la variales de sesion estuvieran llenas. Gracias

En el archivo login.php tengo esto:

```
session_start();
require_once("conexion.php");
 $contra = $_POST['contra'];
 $email = $_POST['mail'];
$consulogin = "select * from usuario
where email = '{$email}'
 and contrasena='{$contra}' ";

 $res = $lnk->query($consulogin); 
 $numeroderegistros = $res->num_rows;
 $fila = $res->fetch_object();

if($numeroderegistros==1){
        if($fila->nivel==0){
            $_SESSION['sesion']=0;

        } else {

            $_SESSION['sesion']=1;
            $_SESSION['nombre']=$fila->nick;
            header('location:index.php');

        }

} else {

    header('location:index.php');

}
```

Y en el archivo index.php tengo esto:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sesion']) && $_SESSION['sesion']==true ){
                echo "hola ".$_SESSION['nombre']." bienvenido";*/

            } else { ?>

           <form id="login" method="post" action="login.php" ><br>
        Email: <br>
  <input type="email" name="mail" ><br>
  Contraseña: <br>
  <input type="password" name="contra" autocomplete="new-password"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Tienes algún include en el index.php que hayas puesto algún session_start() y que este heredando sesiones ???

Comment: Tengo includes pero no tienen ninguno session_start()

Comment: revisa el php.ini, probablemente tienes configurado [session.auto_start](http://php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) aunque no esté configurado en el php.ini, puede que Apache o PHP-FPM lo estén sobreescribiendo. Haz un `phpinfo()` para comprobarlo

Comment: Pero donde lo pone en php info y a que lugar del php.ini tengo que ir para cambiarlo. Gracias muy amable.

Comment: Ya lo he mirado lo tengo en off.

Answer (score 1):

A ver te estas liando, si rediriges al index.php y haces esta comprobacion es que necesitas usar sesion, porque estas usando $_SESSION, en el index.php lo que tienes que hacer en ese IF es identificar al usuario y hacer un logout para destruir la sesión "session_destroy()" y que te aparezca de nuevo el formulario de login

```
        if(isset($_SESSION['sesion']) && $_SESSION['sesion']==1){
            echo "hola ".$_SESSION['nombre']." bienvenido";*/
            /* Y AQUI COMO YA TIENES SESION SIEMPRE TE ENTRARA AQUI
               A MENOS QUE HAGAS UN FORMULARIO Y QUE TE HAGA UN 
               SESSION_DESTROY();*/
        } else { ?>

       <form id="login" method="post" action="login.php" ><br>
         Email: <br>
         <input type="email" name="mail" ><br>
         Contraseña: <br>
         <input type="password" name="contra" autocomplete="new-password"> 
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
       </form> 
    <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

¡no te olvides de poner el session_start() en el index.php porque al final si que lo vas a usar!